# Facial recognition sites

Tags: webapp-rec

What sites exist that do facial recognition?

We just had a family reunion and I'd like to be able to have my photos auto-tagged with the people in them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific web app’s feature(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picasa Web Albums has the same [Name Tags and Facial Recognition](http://picasa.google.com/features-nametags.html) that Picasa Desktop does.

Answer (score 2):

[face.com](http://face.com) works with photos in Facebook.